# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

When I click on submit button my data is showing in console but after that I get this error in screen and in console both.

Create Post Action Creator

```
export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createPost(post);

    dispatch({ type: "CREATE", payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Onclick Function

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(createPost(postData));
  };
```

Comment: You "Dispatch" an action in your action you don't dispatch anything, return the new value.

on your `onClick={createPost}`
then you can dispatch, your reducer action `{type: "CREATE_POST",payload:postData}`

Comment: The error is telling you that you need a middleware like [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or saga to handle such type of Async actions. Or, you can use a new [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) library which takes away lots of boilerplate setup code.